# OpenGL ES: glOrtho() shows object, but gluPerspective() doesn't

Tags: android, opengl-es, glulookat

I am showing a textured sqad, centered around [0,0,-10], width and height = 10000. The camera is positioned at [0,0,0] and looks down the negative z-axis (eyepoint=[0,0,0], center=[0,0,-1]):

```
GLU.gluLookAt(gl, 0f, 0f, 0f, 0f, 0f, -1f, 0f, 1f, 0f);
```

Lighting and Depth-Test are disabled.

In orthographic mode, the squad is displayed perfectly, with texture and all - I can even zoom and pan around.
However, when switching to perspective mode, via:

```
GLU.gluPerspective(gl, 60.0f, w / h, 1.0f, 1000.0f);
```

then the view is just blank. Has anybody got any idea what could cause this?

**UPDATE:**

Using glFrustum instead of gluPerspective, it works:

```
gl.glFrustumf(-scaledHalfW, scaledHalfW, -scaledhalfH, scaledhalfH, 1.0f, 100.0f);
```

But why does gluPerspective not show anything?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is `w / h` an integer division maybe?

Comment: it is! omg feeling stupid right now :) w/h will be 0, distorting the viewport to exactly 0 width.